# Azure devops repo to download a particular file from repo using RestApi

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to download a particular file abc.pdf from azure devops repository using RestApi's.  I was able to download the required file i wanted but not able to open the downloaded pdf file and also noted that downloaded file is twice the size of the original file in the repo.

```
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project)/_apis/git/repositories/$($repoId)/items?Path=$($appPath)&download=true&api-version=5.1"
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repoId/blobs/$($sha1_blob)?download=true&fileName=abc.pdf&api-version=5.1"
```

`$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $header
$result | out-file "abc.pdf"`

I am using powershell to make the rest call and tried with the above 2 url to download the file and it's downloading the file but at twice the size of the original..
am I missing something overhere?? these 2 are the restapi url i have used!!!
[link for git blob from azure devops restapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/blobs/get%20blob?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

[link for items to download from azure devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the seperate `$result | out-file "abc.pdf"` with the encodings for pdf file.
instead used -outfile parameter in invoke-restmethod itself and the pdf file was copied successfully.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -outfile "abc.pdf"
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.